# good ADT to implement BTREE

Tags: b-tree, abstract-data-type

What data structure should I use to implement a BTree? Why?

Comment: A BTree *is* a data structure. So this is kind of a weird question. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a btree node using following class.. it is having 7 keys and 8 pointers. u can change it according to the definition of btree node and perform operations on it

```
class BTNode
{
   BTNode pointers[];
   String keys[];
   int numKeys;
   boolean leaf;

   public BTNode()  // constructor to initialize values
   {
     leaf=true;
     numKeys=0;
     keys=new String[7];
     pointers=new BTNode[8];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Node {
   int data;
   Node left;
   Node right;
}

class BNode {
   Node[] nodes;
}
```

This way you will have pointers to every node of the BNode to point to the right and left subtree....

Answer (score 0):

I implemented BTree in a few days ago with LinkedList (delete O(1), insert O(1)). I will show you my code. Here is my BNode structure:

```
public class BTree {
    private int order;
    private BNode root;


    public BTree(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public void insert(int value){}
    public boolean delete(int value){}
    public boolean contains(int value){}
    public void print(){}

}

class BNode{
    private LinkedList<Integer> values;
    private LinkedList<BNode> children;

    public BNode(){
        init(values);
        init(children); // every bnode with order k has k+1 children 
    }


}
```